# waitForNextUpdate alternative in renderHook

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I've updated Testing-library and I'm struggling to find and alternative to `waitForNextUpdate` in this case (it is no longer available in `react-testing-library` v13 https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/1101). I've tried to use `rerender()` it seems it is not helping:

```
const mockGetSummary = getSummary as jest.MockedFunction<any>;

test('initial state of hook', async () => {
    mockGetSummary.mockImplementation(() => ({
      setOptions: () => ({
        call: () => Promise.resolve({mycustomObject}),
      }),
    }));

    const { result, rerender } = renderHook(() => useHomePageData());

    expect(result.current).toMatchObject({
      loading: true,
      stats: null
    });

    await waitForNextUpdate(); // <--- how to wait for the hook to be executed? 

    expect(result.current).toMatchObject({
      loading: false,
      stats: {...}
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of React Testing Library, `waitForNextUpdate()` is no longer available. Instead, you can handle the asynchronous updates using the act function, which is also provided by `@testing-library/react-hooks`.

try this code:

```
 import { renderHook, act } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';
 import { waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';

 const mockGetSummary = getSummary as jest.MockedFunction<any>;

 test('initial state of hook', async () => {
    mockGetSummary.mockImplementation(() => ({
      setOptions: () => ({
      call: () => Promise.resolve({ mycustomObject }),
      }),
  }));

 const { result } = renderHook(() => useHomePageData());

 expect(result.current).toMatchObject({
   loading: true,
   stats: null,
 });

 // Wait for the asynchronous update to finish using act and waitFor
 await act(async () => {
 await waitFor(() => {
    return !result.current.loading;
 });
 });

 expect(result.current).toMatchObject({
   loading: false,
   stats: { ... },
});
});
```

Using `act` ensures that the component updates are handled correctly

Comment: Thanks. There are 2 problems with this though: I get a warning `ESLint: Avoid wrapping Testing Library util calls in act (testing-library/no-unnecessary-act)`, and, more important, the test still fails `Error: thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.`

Comment: I'm using `@testing-library/react:13.4.0` so I don't have `testing-library/react-hook` as a dep btw. https://github.com/testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library

Answer (score 0):

I can find a related Github topic [here](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/1101) and the answer of [eps1lon](https://github.com/eps1lon), member of testing librariry, was:

> the next update isn't necessarily relevant to the user. We want to discourage testing these implementation in Testing Library. waitFor has all the tools you need.

#### `waitFor`

> When in need to wait for any period of time you can use waitFor, to wait for your expectations to pass. Returning a falsy condition is not sufficient to trigger a retry, the callback must throw an error in order to retry the condition.

[docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor)

Comment: I'm perfectly aware of that. That is the whole point of this question.

Comment: @alfredopacino I don't get your point, if you are aware of `waitFor` then you are aware of `waitForNextUpdate` alternative isn't you?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced a similar issue (I couldn't make my code work with `waitForNextUpdate`) On latest version, [`rerender`](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/reference/api#renderhook) only returns an object with three keys (current, all and error), in order to execute asynchronous actions you need to import `waitFor` from `@testing-library/react`

Your code would look like this

```
 import { renderHook, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';

  test('initial state of hook', async () => {
    mockGetSummary.mockImplementation(() => ({
      setOptions: () => ({
        call: () => Promise.resolve({mycustomObject}),
      }),
    }));

    const { result } = renderHook(() => useHomePageData());

    expect(result.current).toMatchObject({
      loading: true,
      stats: null
    });

    await waitFor(() => {
      //call your async function for example
      //result.current.fetchSummary()
    });

    expect(result.current).toMatchObject({
      loading: false,
      stats: {...}
    });
  });
```